# Purifier's ability effect on Blood Priest

Tags: werewolv.es

BMC has one user of witchcraft, the Blood Priest. If a Purifier uses their ability on the Priest, what role do they become?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, the answer *was* nothing, as the Purifier did not correctly handle BMC roles.

This has been fixed now, the only WC using BMC roles are [BloodPriest](https://werewolv.es/guides/roles/BloodPriest) and [BloodSeer](https://werewolv.es/guides/roles/BloodSeer), and if they are targeted by a Purifier they will become a Cultist.